# Distribute divs over one line based on their given share in percents

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make a one-line graph of items that describes their distribution over time. Let's use seasons as an example.

The HTML is generated from backend data. It may be changed to suit the layout needs, but I was hoping width in percent would be the right solution. The CSS is my attempt, using flexbox hoping it would force the items, literally, in line.

```css
html, body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
div.season {
    display: inline-block;
    flex: none;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="season" width="47.150002%" style="background-color:rgb(156, 203, 205);">
          winter
        </div>
        <div class="season" width="19.520000%" style="background-color:rgb(160, 201, 166);">
          summer_heat
        </div>
        <div class="season" width="26.639997%" style="background-color:rgb(192, 204, 157);">
          fall
        </div>
        <div class="season" width="6.690001%" style="background-color:rgb(156, 203, 205);">
          winter
        </div>
    </div>
```

The result is that the items are only as big as their content. The expected result is more like this (I can live without the black separators):

[image]

Why doesn't the flex layout make the items grow by their percent share?

Comment: To set the width of the div's , you'll need to set it via the `style` attribute `style="width:47%"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, the reason your widths are failing is because the `width` *attribute* is not valid on `<div>`s. You need to move it into the `style` attribute.

However I'm chiming in to show how, with a simple adjustment, we can include the black seperators from your image.

There exists in CSS3 a wonderful tool called `calc` - among other things this can be used to apply pixel adjustments on percentages. Using this, we can adjust the width down from 100% by the total cumulative width of our dividers (12px in this case, for 4px per divider), and then multiply by the widths of the bars presented as a decimal.

We can then use CSS's `flex` `justify-content: space-between;` and a background colour to introduce the dividers.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="season" style="width: calc((100% - 12px) * 0.47150002); background-color: rgb(156, 203, 205);">
    winter
  </div>
  <div class="season" style="width: calc((100% - 12px) * 0.19520000); background-color: rgb(160, 201, 166);">
    summer_heat
  </div>
  <div class="season" style="width: calc((100% - 12px) * 0.26639997); background-color: rgb(192, 204, 157);">
    fall
  </div>
  <div class="season" style="width: calc((100% - 12px) * 0.06690001); background-color: rgb(156, 203, 205);">
    winter
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, your solution is even better than the one that produced the original screenshot, where the black bars are actually not accounted for and cause small shifts in the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Only the following elements support the width attribute:

```
<canvas>, <embed>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <object>, <video>
```

For a div use the style attribute like this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="season" style="width:47.150002%; background-color:rgb(156, 203, 205);">
      winter
    </div>
    <div class="season" style="width:19.520000%; background-color:rgb(160, 201, 166);">
      summer_heat
    </div>
    <div class="season" style="width:26.639997%; background-color:rgb(192, 204, 157);">
      fall
    </div>
    <div class="season" style="width:6.690001%; background-color:rgb(156, 203, 205);">
      winter
    </div>
</div>
```